# PowerApps formula for matching records from a drop down

Tags: dropdown, powerapps

I'm trying to build a login form that performs a simple check against the user's PIN.  The pin in stored in the database as a field in the Person entity (table).

I have a Team entity that allows the Person to select the Team they are on from a dropdown list of all Teams.  The Person entity dropdown then populates based on the Person's TeamID.  The User selects their Name and enters a PIN number in the `txtPinNumber` textbox.

The `Login` button is hidden by default and should only have `visible = true` when the pin entered into `txtPinNumber` is the same as the PIN field in the database.

I have the `visible` property of the `btnLogin` button set to

`If(txtPinNumber.Text=Filter(Personnel,ddResponder.Selected.PIN),true,false)`

However, I'm getting an error of unspecified type.  Is it because I'm trying to check the entered PIN against a filtered datatype?

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're having difficulty because of your usage of the `Filter()` function. `Filter()` returns a table with all of the rows that meet a given criteria. However, it seems that `ddResponder.Selected.Pin` is the PIN you are seeking to match. If this is the case, you can simply have the visible property set to:

`txtPinNumber.Text = ddResponder.Selected.Pin`

If, however you need to do a search in your table to find the relevant PIN, you will instead want to use the `Lookup()` function.

You can see the documentation for these functions here:
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-filter-lookup/

The `Lookup()` function will return the first matching row based on the criteria you provide, otherwise it will return a blank. You can use this with the `IsBlank()` function to determine whether or not to display the button.

Comment: I discovered that the PIN is being passed as part of the record for the User, so no lookup is necessary.  Thanks!